# Fiddler not logging https traffic form IIS

Tags: https, fiddler

I've configured fiddler as proxy for my web application. My web application makes makes https requests to API using RestClient. These HTTPS requests are not showing on fiddler.

I've enabled "Decrypt Https Traffic" that install fiddler certificate. still it does not work. any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

By default fiddler sets itself up as a proxy for WinINet which is used by browsers. IIS doesn't use WinINet.

Check out this article:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Comment: Check this out also:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-how-to-configure-to-capture-w3wp-process-traffic